# Void method for println vs. println with return method

Tags: java, methods, return

While I was writing a calculator app, I just couldn't figure out what the best way to do this is:

```
private void calculate(String command) {
    System.out.print("value1: ");
    int value1 = reader.readInteger();
    System.out.print("value2: ");
    int value2 = reader.readInteger();

    if (command.equals("sum"))
        System.out.println("sum of the values " + sum(value1 + value2));
}

private int sum(int value1, int value2) {
    return value1 + value2;
}
```

or

```
private void calculate(String command) {
    System.out.print("value1: ");
    int value1 = reader.readInteger();
    System.out.print("value2: ");
    int value2 = reader.readInteger();

    if (command.equals("sum"))
        sum();
}

private void sum(int value1, int value2) {
    System.out.println("sum of the values " + value1 + value2);
}
```

The second one makes the `calculate()` method cleaner, but is it generally preferred to use return methods or void(just for the printline)?

Comment: Is it necessary to have a function which adds two integers and returns the result? That is already what `+` does. You could just do `System.out.println("sum of the values " + (value1 + value2));`  Though to answer your question, a method with a return type is usually preferred.

Comment: You might try posting this on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: It surely isn't necessary to add a method for sum but what's the point of good programming overall then? Just add everything in the main method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it's better to *return* value - then you can test your method and reuse it in more complex calculations.

One of the good approaches is to define some `calculate` method which calculates and returns value, and define `void show` method which will accept as argument value to show on the screen and properly show it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should take a look at `command pattern` if you will extend this to other commands. 
It will reduce your if statements in future when you want extend this calculate method.

[command-pattern with calculator](http://twit88.com/blog/2008/01/26/design-pattern-in-java-101-command-pattern-behavioral-pattern/)

Answer (score 3):

Better way is the returning value. If you named the method `sum`, you expect to get *value of sum*.

You might create a method `showResult()`. You expect to get a *information message*.

```
public int getSum() {
    return this.sum;
}

public void showResult() {
    System.out.println("sum = " + this.sum); // add some description 
}

private void calculate() {
    this.sum = reader.readInteger() + reader.readInteger();
}
```